# How to check if a file exists in Firebase storage when trying to download multiple files - javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I have a Arrylist of names of folders&files that I need to download from firebase storage.

It's throwing exceptions because some of thus folders&files doesn't exists in firebase storage .
Is't possible to detect thus folders&files without throwing exceptions ?

**JS CODE:**

```
var parNum = 'S3DD4';
var sessionNum = '3333';
var storageInfoarr = ["Testing/Testing1.3gp", "Testing/Testing1.xlsx"];
 for (i = 0 ; i< storageInfoarr.length; i++){
    var starsRef = storageRef.child(parNum+'/'+sessionNum+'/'+storageInfoarr[i])
    var urlString = starsRef.getDownloadURL().catch(function(error) {
    switch (error.code) {
      case 'storage/object_not_found': // <<< here you decide what to do when the file doesn't exist
        // File doesn't exist
        break;

      case 'storage/unauthorized':
        // User doesn't have permission to access the object
        break;

      case 'storage/canceled':
        // User canceled the upload
        break;

    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

getDownloadUrl() will always throw exception when path is incorrect, what you can do is handle these exceptions and only download files which are present. You can create a consolidated promise which tells if some of the path are correct and incorrect and handle them accordingly.

```
var parNum = 'S3DD4';
var sessionNum = '3333';
var storageInfoarr = ["Testing/Testing1.3gp", "Testing/Testing1.xlsx"];

Promise.all(storageInfoarr.map((sStorage) => {
    var starsRef = storageRef.child(parNum+'/'+sessionNum+'/'+sStorage);
    starsRef.getDownloadURL().then(url => {
        // url is download url, use it download the file
    }).catch(err => {
       // Here you can handle the error for individual download
    });
}) ).then((aResponses) => {
   // This will be called if all promises are resolved. aResponses contain all download url
}).catch((err) => {
   // This will be called if any of the download path is incorrect, with the error of first promise which fails
});
```

Comment: Still throwing exceptions

Comment: It will always throw exception, you need to handle them properly as shown in the code provided.